# Keyboard settings are not saved properly on servers using a domain account

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Scenario :

10 servers in the same datacenter and i connect remotely of course using my german keyboard. All my profile settings were always german on serverside and i never had problems with it.
Somehow now the profiles on server always switch back to US and i have to change my keyboard settings after every login.

Does anyone know a possible reason for that ? No one else is using my account.
On servers we have windows server 2008 / 2012

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a Domain GPO or local GPO. As these settings are stored in your profile. If it's not GPO related your profile might be corrupt I would then try deleting it and logging back on to recreate a new one.

Note recreating your account will not work if the wrong keyboard settings have been saved to the default account. When your profile is recreated it will copy from the default account and take the default language and keyboard setting that are stored.

Also under the control panel you can go to region and language and keyboards and languages and make sure you only have the german keyboard listed or move that to the top of the list.